# Spring Batch not making full use of multi-core CPU

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-batch, spring-batch-stream

I have a spring batch application which reads lines from a flat file, converts each line to an object, processes them, and writes them to a database.
The steps are multi-threaded using spring's ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, but the performance is still terrible.
Logging shows that reading is the main bottleneck, with a speed of 25 lines per second. Reading is multi-threaded and runs on 16 threads. But CPU utilization only shows 6 - 7% usage. The application is running on a 16-core 64GB RAM system, with a Tomcat Server.
I suspect that it's not using all CPU cores. How can I configure Spring Batch to better utilize the CPU?

Step Configuration :

```
    public Step createMyStep() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Creating MyStep");
            AbstractTaskletStepBuilder builder = stepFactory.get("MyStep")
                    .<T, T>chunk(50)
                    .reader(multiResourceItemReader(null, null, null, null, null))
                    .listener(new ItemReadListenerImpl<>())
                    .processor(createProcessor())
                    .listener(new ItemProcessListenerImpl<>())
                    .writer(slaveStepWriter())
                    .faultTolerant()
                    .skip(RollbackException.class)
                    .skipLimit(1000000000)
                    .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                    .throttleLimit(64);
            return builder.build();
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(16);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(1);
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        return executor;
    }DataLoadConstants
```

The reader takes an InputStream as a resource, and uses FlatFileItemReader, configured with a  lineMapper and BufferedReaderFactory to convert lines to an Object. The reader returns a SynchronizedItemStreamReader.

Comment: Fixed this by using Spring Batch Partitioner

Comment: This issue was caused by an inefficient reader design. Once i fixed that, CPU utilization rose to expected levels.